# Apostrophe prints out to terminal when concatenating a string

Tags: python

fairly new to python coding.
Currently using python 3.11.6

I've been given a task to ask for a user input for their name, age, street number and street address and to print out a single sentence containing all those details

I have configured a code for this task
It seems to be working fine, but the only issue is that once it prints the output variable it prints it as:

```
('Hi Phil', ' you are 7 years old. You live at 89a', ' hollywood')
```

For some reason I do not know, apostrophes show up surrounding the name, after the inputted house number and surrounding the street name

I'm not sure if it has to do with added commas to separate the variables but I only added in the comma's because it shows up as a syntax error without it

```
name =  str(input("What is your name: "))
age = int(input("What is your age: "))
house_number = str(input("what is your house number: "))
street_name = str(input("What is your street name: "))
output = ("Hi " +name, " you are " +str(age) +" years old. You live at " +house_number, ' ' +street_name )
print (output)
```

with this code I was expecting it to print out:

```
Hello (name), you are (age) years old. You live at (house number, street name)
```

but it prints out:

```
'Hi (name)', ' you are (age) years old. You live at (house no.)', ' (street name)'
```

just wondering how to remove the apostrophes in the printed output and why that's happening

Comment: Save yourself some grief and just use an f-string. `output = f"Hi {name} you are {age} years old. You live at {house_number} {street_name}"`

Comment: The commas must be inside the quotes.

Comment: haha, this has definitely saved me some grief.
Thanks all for your help

Answer (score 2):

The way you have declared `output` makes a tuple.  Tuples are displayed in parentheses and comma-separated.  Instead, put the value of `output` directly in a `print`:

```
>>> output = 1,2,3
>>> print(output)
(1, 2, 3)
>>> print(1,2,3)
1 2 3
```

In your case:

```py
print("Hi " +name, " you are " +str(age) +" years old. You live at " +house_number, ' ' +street_name )
```

Or using Python's formatting strings (f-strings):

```
print(f'Hi {name}, you are {age} years old.  You live at {house_number} {street_name}')
```

Comment: It may be worth noting that `print` will insert spaces between arguments unless the default separator is overridden. Combined with the spaces already in the strings, that may cause unexpected output.

Comment: @Chris True, which is why f-strings are more straightforward.  To OP, use `sep=''` as a print option or adjust the spacing.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've separated the concatenated strings using commas while assigning to the `output` variable, Python treats the whole thing as a [tuple](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_tuples.asp). When the values in a tuple are printed, the strings are wrapped in quotes by default. To solve your problem, you can use f-strings or the `.format()` method. Using f-string:

```
print(f"Hi {name}, you are {age} years old.  You live at {house_number} {street_name}")
```

Using `.format()`:

```
print("Hi {}, you are {} years old.  You live at {house_number} {street_name}".format(name,age,house_number,street_name))
```

Comment: Note is it not the parenthesis that make a tuple.  It is the commas.  If you write, `output = 'hi', 'phil'`, `output` is still a tuple.

Comment: @Malcolm I've edited my answer. I didn't know that you could define tuples without parentheses

Comment: It is definitely odd, and not having the parentheses looks strange.  However, this is why `x = ('test')` does not make `x` a one element tuple, and you need to write `x = ('test',)` instead.